# Show Admob ads from service context Android

Tags: admob

I want to show ads from a running service. My service check clipboard for text, and show a popup windows with information (dictionary service). But when i debug the app, it's show error:

```
Could not initialize AdView: AdView was initialized with a Context that wasn't an Activity.
```

Some one said that it's can not start without activity context. Is there any solution with this?

I update the code below:
Code to show popup windows:

```
    private void showCaptureWindow() {

    setTextToKeywordEdit(mClipboardText);

    makeDictContent(mClipboardText);

    if(!mDictContentView.hasFocus())
        mDictContentView.requestFocus();

    if(false == bHasAddedView)
    {
        int bgColor = MultiDictUtils.GetBgColor();
        int textColor = MultiDictUtils.GetTextColor();
        mParentViewLayout.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        mDictContentView.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        mLineView0.setBackgroundColor(textColor);
        mLineView1.setBackgroundColor(textColor);
        mLineView2.setBackgroundColor(textColor);
        mLineView3.setBackgroundColor(textColor);
        mLineView4.setBackgroundColor(textColor);           

        updateDisplaySize(true);

        mWindowParams.x = mWindow_Default_X;
        mWindowParams.y = mWindow_Default_Y;

        mWinStatus = 0;
        mWindowResizeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_max_win);
        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        adView = (AdView)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        mWindowManager.addView(mCaptureWindowLayout, mWindowParams);
        bHasAddedView = true;
    }
}
```

Init the service:

```
    private void initService() {
    MyLog.v(TAG, "initService()");

    mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    if(mClipboardManager.hasText())
    {
        mClipboardText = mClipboardManager.getText().toString();
    }

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mCaptureWindowLayout = (LinearLayout)factory.inflate(R.layout.capture_window, null);

    mWindowCloseBtn = (ImageButton)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.windowCloseBtn);
    mWindowResizeBtn = (ImageButton)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.windowResizeBtn);
    mWindowMoveBtn = (ImageButton)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.windowMoveBtn);
    mWindowSchBtn = (ImageButton)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.windowSchBtn);

    mKeywordEdit = (EditText)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.keywordTxt);

    mParentViewLayout = (LinearLayout) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    mLineView0 = (View) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineView0);
    mLineView1 = (View) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineView1);
    mLineView2 = (View) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineView2);
    mLineView3 = (View) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineView3);
    mLineView4 = (View) mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineView4);
    mDictContentView = (WebView)mCaptureWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.dictContentWindow);
    mDictContentView.setWebViewClient(new DictWebViewClient(new ServiceWebViewClientCallback()));

    WebSettings webSettings = mDictContentView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Oncreate:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {

    mMultiDictUtils = new MultiDictUtils(this);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    mClipboardTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            clipboardCheck();

            mHandler.postDelayed(mClipboardTask, CLIPBOARD_TIMER);
        }
    };

    Runnable initServiceTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            initService();

            mHandler.postDelayed(mClipboardTask, CLIPBOARD_TIMER);
        }
    };

    mHandler.postDelayed(initServiceTask, 5000);

    super.onCreate();
}
```

Sory because i can not post full code here. There service check clipboard and then show content in o view layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can show an Ad in your popup window (I presume you mean an Activity that you are starting from your service). The error you are getting is because you are creating an AdView using a Context object that is not an Activity. Pass in the Activity that is your popup window.

Comment: But i use serivce to findview and display content.

Comment: You are not making sense. Update your question to include some code showing how you findView from your Service.

Comment: @William can I load Interstitial ads from service?

Comment: @Giru, I'm not sure. I suspect not. But just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't edit your code but Yes, we can show Admob ads from service. Here is the code I am using in my application for InterstitialAd :

```
public class ServiceAd extends Service {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            Log.d("tag", "on closed ad");
        }

    });

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("tag", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    }, 5000);   // 5 mins
    return START_STICKY;
}}
```

First I run code without handler and ad was not loaded so I gave some time to load ad first.

Hope this will help.